# NodeJS Updating User Bcrypt - Password doesn't get hashed

Tags: node.js, passport.js, updates, bcrypt, passport-local

I'm trying to set set up an update function for user profiles on a Node.JS application with hash passwords using the bcrypt-nodejs module. It works when signing in, but when I am updating the profile it updates the user object with the plain text (i.e.: I type "text" for the password, the db shows "text"). I would like to hash the password when the profile is updated. How would I fix this?

Below is my code for the controller:

```
exports.editUser = function(req, res) {
 // user edit form set to findonendupdate
 User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.user_id, randString: req.body.randString }, req.body, function(err, user) { 

   if (err) 
    res.send(err); 
   res.json({ data: user }); 
 });
};
```

For reference this is the user model code that works with a new user registration:

```
 passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, callback) {
   User.findOne({ username: username } , function (err, user) {
     if (err) { return callback(err); }

     // No user found with that username
     if (!user) { return callback(null, false); }

     // Make sure the password is correct
     user.verifyPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
       if (err) { return callback(err); }

     // Password did not match
       if (!isMatch) { return callback(null, false); }

     // Success
       return callback(null, user);
     });
  });
 }
));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({...}, req.body, function(err,...
```

Here you're receiving the password in `req.body` and telling it to update it directly as it is (plain text).

You need to hash it and then update

```
// retrieve the password field
var password = req.body.password

// update it with hash
bcrypt.hash(password, (hash) => {
  req.body.password = hash

  // then update
  User.findByIdAndUpdate({...}, req.body, function(err,... // then update
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved by converting plain text password to hashed password before updating password.

```
req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 8);

await Admin.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body._id }, req.body, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
                    if (!err) { 
                        req.flash('success', 'Admin Updated successfully!');
                        res.status(201).render('admin-views/admin/edit_admin', { success_message: req.flash('success'), admin: doc });
                    }
                    else {
                        res.render("admin-views/admin/edit_admin", {
                            admin: req.body
                        })
                    }
                })
```

hope this code is works!